# Can Keychain Deal with a Login, a Password, and a PIN?

Tags: safari, security, password, keychain

To log in, a financial institution's website requires a user name, a password, and a PIN. Keychain happily memorizes the user name and the password. But if I ask Keychain to memorize the PIN, Keychain does so but substitutes the PIN for the password. Is there a way to direct or allow Keychain to memorize all three inputs for this site?

macOS 10.12.6, Safari 11

Comment: I haven't got a clue.... Third party password managers should support that... I'm pretty sure [1password](https://1password.com) can do it. There are free password managers too...

Comment: I should point out that 1pass does still offer the 1 time purchase license, though they reeeaaaallly want you to purchase the cloud plans (so it's well hidden in the old site page). I'm not a 100% sure if it is still in the App Store, but if you download the trial, and find license option in the menu, that should lead to the old store page, where it's listed. Though it should also be pointed out that it requires you to self manage the vault storage/hosting. Popular method is Dropbox sync.

Comment: The 1password standalone option appears when one clicks on the "buy" link. But for me, Keychain is good enough. I'll just memorize the PIN. <g>

Comment: If we are not talking about some sort of high security thing, you could perhaps use a third party app for filling in the pin. Like press a shortcut and it automatically writes in the pin. Many different ways to do that....

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility as well. Thanks for your thoughts.